# Using a list for comparing strings of unequal lengths

Tags: python

I have a list of strings, I am trying to iterate over the characters of each string in the list by using 
`if NEXT_individual_CHAR != individual_CHAR:` and outputting the characters that are not the same at there given index, but so far I keep getting `Index Out of Bounds` error messages, and I can't seem to properly output the length of the larger or smaller string, or properly report which actual string is bigger than the other. The commented out lines are the lines that are suppose to show which is bigger and which is smaller, along with a few lines that are there just to test output. Finally, I couldn't figure out how to display the remaining character if one string is longer than the other ie, say s1=`red` and s2 = `redford` how would I display `print(f"{s1} is shorter than {s2} and by {n} and {s2} still has the chars o, r, d remaining"`

I'm new to posting and coding in general, so feed back is greatly appreciated, especially if there are some new and useful methods/ keywords that I haven't seen before.

```
array = "red redford grimbolt".split()  

print(array)

for string in range( len(array) ) :
    print()

    print(f"we are at iteration number : {string+1}") #tests output for string
    print()

    individual_string = array[string]
    print()

    print(f"indivudal_string is '{individual_string} '")
    print()

    print(f"the length of the string '{individual_string}' is '{len(individual_string) }'")
    print()

    NEXT_individual_string = array[string +1]
  # smaller_string = min[ NEXT_individual_string , individual_string]

  # 
  # bigger_string = max[ individual_string , NEXT_individual_string]
  #

  # print(f"indivudal_string is '{individual_string}' and NEXT_individual_string is '{NEXT_individual_string}'  " ) # test output
  # print()
  # print(f"bigger_string = '{bigger_string}' and smaller string =  '{smaller_string}'  ") # test output of bigger_string and smaller_string

  # small_len = len(smaller_string)
  #
  # big_len  = len(bigger_string)
  #
  # print()
  #
  # print(f"small len is {small_len} and big len is {big_len}")
  # print()

    for char in range( len(individual_string)  ):

        individual_CHAR = individual_string[char]
        NEXT_individual_CHAR = NEXT_individual_string[char]

        #if small_len > big_len:
        #    print(f"small len is not smaller than big len...small_len right now = {small_len}  and big_len right now is {big_len}")



        if NEXT_individual_CHAR != individual_CHAR:

            print(f" '{individual_CHAR}' at position {char+1} in the string '{individual_string}' is the not same '{NEXT_individual_CHAR}' at position {char+1} in the string '{NEXT_individual_string}'   ")
```

With those lines commented out I get this output:

````
we are at iteration number : 1


indivudal_string is 'red '

the length of the string 'red' is '3'


we are at iteration number : 2


indivudal_string is 'redford '

the length of the string 'redford' is '7'

 'r' at position 1 in the string 'redford' is the not same 'g' at position 1 in the string 'grimbolt'   
 'e' at position 2 in the string 'redford' is the not same 'r' at position 2 in the string 'grimbolt'   
 'd' at position 3 in the string 'redford' is the not same 'i' at position 3 in the string 'grimbolt'   
 'f' at position 4 in the string 'redford' is the not same 'm' at position 4 in the string 'grimbolt'   
 'o' at position 5 in the string 'redford' is the not same 'b' at position 5 in the string 'grimbolt'   
 'r' at position 6 in the string 'redford' is the not same 'o' at position 6 in the string 'grimbolt'   
 'd' at position 7 in the string 'redford' is the not same 'l' at position 7 in the string 'grimbolt'   

we are at iteration number : 3


indivudal_string is 'grimbolt '

the length of the string 'grimbolt' is '8'



```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "
/Library/Preferences/PyCharmEdu2019.2/scratches/Comparing an Array of Strings.py", line 25, in <module>
    NEXT_individual_string = array[string +1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1```


but without those lines commented out I get :


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//Library/Preferences/PyCharmEdu2019.2/scratches/Comparing an Array of Strings.py", line 26, in <module>
    smaller_string = min[ NEXT_individual_string , individual_string]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
['red', 'redford', 'grimbolt']

we are at iteration number : 1


indivudal_string is 'red '

the length of the string 'red' is '3'


Process finished with exit code 1 ```
````

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very verbose way to accomplish your task (below).

The main things to read up on to complete your own solution to this
are **Try/Except** blocks and **list indexing**. The former of these
two will allow you to test for IndexError (or other errors) and simply continue if you encounter one. The latter will allow you to check all the elements in a list, except for a single element (in this case a word). For example, if my list is ["I","love","chocolate"] and you want to look at everything before and after "love" but not "love" itself, you could, given that the index of "love" is 1, check list[:list.index("love")] and check list[list.index("love") + 1:]. The 
first list in each of the code blocks is a placeholder for your list name. The brackets mean a list. my_list = [] (empty list). my_list[:] means everything in the list. my_list[1:] means everything in the list from element 1 onwards (the first index of a list is 0). my_list[:7] means everything up to but not including the 7th element. For the "love" example, the first my_list[filler] get everything up to but not including the "love" element and the next my_list[filler2] means everything in the list starting after "love". Hope some of this helped. Ask me questions if you have them.

The general approach goes as follows:

```
for each word in word list
     check every word in the word list before current word
     use shorter of the two words to know when to stop checking
     print differences and information

     check every word in the word list after current word
     use shorter of the two words to know when to stop checking
     print differences and information
```

```
array = "red green blue".split()

for string_index in range(len(array)):
    one_string = array[string_index]
    shortest = ''
    print(f"We are at iteration {string_index}, and the word is {array[string_index]}")
    for other_str in array[:string_index]:
        if len(one_string) > len(other_str):
            shortest = len(other_str)
        else:
            shortest = len(one_string)
        try:
            for char_index in range(shortest):
                if one_string[char_index] != other_str[char_index]:
                    print(f"{one_string[char_index]} at pos {char_index} in {one_string} != \                                 
{other_str[char_index]} at pos {char_index} in {other_str}")
                else:
                    print(f"{one_string[char_index]} at pos {char_index} in {one_string} == \                                 
{other_str[char_index]} at pos {char_index} in {other_str}")

        except IndexError as error:
            continue
        if shortest == len(other_str):
            print(f"{one_string} is longer than {other_str} by {len(one_string) - len(other_str)}")
            print(f"The leftovers of {one_string} are {[i for i in one_string[len(other_str):]]}")
        if len(one_string) == shortest:
            print(f"{one_string} is shorter than {other_str} by {len(other_str) - len(one_string)}")
            print(f"The leftovers of {other_str} are {[i for i in other_str[len(one_string):]]}")

    for other_str in array[string_index+1:]:
        if len(one_string) > len(other_str):
            shortest = len(other_str)
        else:
            shortest = len(one_string)
        try:
            for char_index in range(len(one_string)):
                if one_string[char_index] != other_str[char_index]:
                    print(f"{one_string[char_index]} at pos {char_index} in {one_string} != \                                 
{other_str[char_index]} at pos {char_index} in {other_str}")
                else:
                    print(f"{one_string[char_index]} at pos {char_index} in {one_string} == \                                 
{other_str[char_index]} at pos {char_index} in {other_str}")
        except IndexError as error:
            continue
        if shortest == len(other_str):
            print(f"{one_string} is longer than {other_str} by {len(one_string) - len(other_str)}")
            print(f"The leftovers of {one_string} are {[i for i in one_string[len(other_str):]]}")
        if len(one_string) == shortest:
            print(f"{one_string} is shorter than {other_str} by {len(other_str) - len(one_string)}")
            print(f"The leftovers of {other_str} are {[i for i in other_str[len(one_string):]]}")
```

Sample Output:

```
We are at iteration 0, and the word is red
r at pos 0 in red != g at pos 0 in green
e at pos 1 in red != r at pos 1 in green
d at pos 2 in red != e at pos 2 in green
red is shorter than green by 2
The leftovers of green are ['e', 'n']
r at pos 0 in red != b at pos 0 in blue
e at pos 1 in red != l at pos 1 in blue
d at pos 2 in red != u at pos 2 in blue
red is shorter than blue by 1
The leftovers of blue are ['e']
We are at iteration 1, and the word is green
g at pos 0 in green != r at pos 0 in red
r at pos 1 in green != e at pos 1 in red
e at pos 2 in green != d at pos 2 in red
green is longer than red by 2
The leftovers of green are ['e', 'n']
g at pos 0 in green != b at pos 0 in blue
r at pos 1 in green != l at pos 1 in blue
e at pos 2 in green != u at pos 2 in blue
e at pos 3 in green == e at pos 3 in blue
We are at iteration 2, and the word is blue
b at pos 0 in blue != r at pos 0 in red
l at pos 1 in blue != e at pos 1 in red
u at pos 2 in blue != d at pos 2 in red
blue is longer than red by 1
The leftovers of blue are ['e']
b at pos 0 in blue != g at pos 0 in green
l at pos 1 in blue != r at pos 1 in green
u at pos 2 in blue != e at pos 2 in green
e at pos 3 in blue == e at pos 3 in green
blue is shorter than green by 1
The leftovers of green are ['n']
```

Comment: This is definitely helpful, in that it gets the job done but also it opens up new things for me to learn, you certainly don't have to teach me everything, but I'm curious as how ```[i for i in other_str[len(one_string):]]``` works, ie, the formating of the loop within the output, and the point of using ``` shortest = '' ```  and you are able to use that to convert it into the an int using ``` shortest = len(other_str) or shortest = len(one_string)```

Comment: Cool, [i for i in range(10)] etc.. (for loops and other things inside the list brackets), are called **list comprehensions**. Imagine it as a for loop expanding itself inside a list and the final result it is the list with all the values in it. For example, my_list = [i for i in range(10)] is [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and is a shorter way of doing my_list = [] (newline) for i in range(10): (newline) my_list.append(i) but a longer way of doing my_list = list(range(10)) Other examples: my_list = [i^2 for i in range(5)] = [0,1,4,9,16], my_list = [i^2 for i in range(5) if i % 2 == 0] = [0,4,16].

Comment: For the line: shortest = '', I am just using this as a place holder for the variable shortest. I could have written, shortest = 0, shortest = [], etc.. it doesn't matter because I instantly update the value and subsequently the type of shortest when I assign it to len(one_string) or len(other_str).